# Querying all unique city names in one state and no where else

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to query all unique city names for one particular state without pulling other states. This is what I am trying to do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT city_name
FROM table
WHERE state = 'California';
```

This does not work because there is a San Diego in other states aside from California. How would I query this so that it only gives me city_names unique only to California and not other US states? Can someone please help? Thank you for your time.

```
SELECT DISTINCT city_name
FROM table
WHERE state = 'California';
```

The desired output is unique city names only in California and no where else.

Comment: is this mysql or postgresql?  please remove one of the tags

Comment: note that in mysql at least, distinct is not a function.  your `select distinct(city_name)` is interpreted as `select distinct (city_name)` which is the same as `select distinct city_name`

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_. `SELECT DISTINCT` will give you distinct _rows_. Simply write `SELECT DISTINCT city_name` to make code clearer.

Comment: Tip: You can use `NOT EXISTS (subquery)` .

Comment: @ysth it was postgresql sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query is using a subquery in the WHERE clause to filter the results from the table "mytable" (aliased as "t1"), by checking that the city_name does not exist in the table with a different state, the subquery uses a NOT EXISTS clause to check that the city_name does not exist in the table "mytable" (aliased as "t2") with a different state than 'California'.

```
select distinct t1.city_name from mytable t1
where state = 'California'
and not exists (select 1 from mytable t2 
                where state != 'California'
                and t2.city_name = t1.city_name)
```

Comment: AFAIK know, a city name is always unique within a state. This means you don't need to do SELECT DISTINCT - which can slow down performance.

Comment: Thank you, Bryan. What does 1 represent in the subquery?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumpkin_Center,_Nodaway_County,_Missouri
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumpkin_Center,_Dallas_County,_Missouri

Comment: a not exists query only checks whether there are any rows returned, so the select field list is unused; so typically just `select 1` is used

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation and set the conditions in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT city_name
FROM tablename
GROUP BY city_name
HAVING COUNT(*) = SUM((state = 'California')::int);
```

`SUM((state = 'California')::int)` will be `1` only for `city_name`s that can be found in `'California'` and it will be `0` for all other `city_name`s.

`COUNT(*)` will be `1` only for `city_name`s that exist in only 1 state (and it is never `0`).

The only case that these expressions are equal is when they are both `1`.

Comment: Thats a cool way to do it! Nice! Thank you for sharing